# How can I remove this gray button feedback from list component in React Native Paper?

Tags: reactjs, list, react-native, button, accordion

[So here is what I need to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6WiJ.jpg)

I tried to do so by customizing the onPress function but nothing actually works. Here is my code:

```
<List.Section style={styles.listSectionStyle}>
                    <List.Accordion
                        title="Language"
                        titleStyle={styles.activeListText}
                        style={[
                            styles.accorditionStyle,
                            {
                                borderBottomLeftRadius: borderRadiusList,
                                borderBottomRightRadius: borderRadiusList
                            }
                        ]}
                        expanded={borderRadiusList === 0 ? true : false}
                        onPress={
                            () =>
                                borderRadiusList === 0 ?
                                    setBorderRadiusList(15) :
                                    setBorderRadiusList(0)
                        }
                    >
                        <List.Item
                            title="Русский"
                            titleStyle={styles.activeListText}
                            style={styles.otherListElements}
                        />
                        <List.Item
                            title="English"
                            titleStyle={styles.inactiveListText}
                            style={styles.otherListElements}
                        />
                        <List.Item
                            title="Español"
                            titleStyle={styles.inactiveListText}
                            style={styles.otherListElements}
                        />
                        <List.Item
                            title="Deutsch"
                            titleStyle={styles.inactiveListText}
                            style={styles.bottomListElement}
                        />
                    </List.Accordion>
                </List.Section>
```

How can I remove this effect in React Native Paper?

Comment: Are you talking about the ripple effect? Do you want to disable it just for this particular list or for the entire application?

Comment: @lidkxx yeah about it. It would be good to disable it for this particular list, but if it can be done for the entire application only, it would be good too